# Choosing a file then asking user what phrase or word they are looking for in file in python

Tags: python, file, parsing, directory

I am trying to make a simple python program which makes it where it asks the user for a word or phrase then it asks the user what file or folder or document to look in and then say how many times that word or phrase comes up and where.

here is the code i have but it seems to stop working on me and i don't know why and don't know python very well. can someone please help me fix this and help me make the program that i explained above?

```
phrase_to_look_for = input("What phrase would you like to look for?")
file_to_search = file.open("my_file.txt")
contents_of_file = file_to_search.read()
if phrase_look_for in contents_of_file:
    print("The word is in the file.")
else:
    print("The phrase is not in the file.")
```

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: it crashes on me and i am not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your file in bash resulted in multiple errors being thrown. The following code successfully executes and I think meets your intent

```
phrase_to_look_for = raw_input("What phrase would you like to look for?")
name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of your file?") #File must be in the same folder
file_to_search = open(name_of_file,'r')
contents_of_file = file_to_search.read()
if phrase_to_look_for in contents_of_file:
    print("The word is in the file.")
else:
    print("The phrase is not in the file.")
```

The reason yours was crashing (originally) was that you needed to do raw_input to get the proper input. This led to the error that file does not have an attribute open -- file. was not needed in this case. Just open.

Comment: You should post the full error in your original question.

Comment: i don't get an error it just closes on me once you input the entry for the first question

Comment: do you mean as in going in and calling it up though command line or clicking on the program which in return pulls up command prompt?

Comment: See the above version, I created a test text file and got the error/traceback and was able to debug from that. In general, if you run from the command prompt or BASH you'll get a full error message along with line numbers. That's very useful for debugging and is what Racialz was getting at

Comment: i just tried complying your code and put in the word _test_ and as soon as i clicked enter i received an error 'Traceback (most recent call last: File "C:\Users\Jared\Desktop\untitled text.py", line 2, in <module> IOError: [Errno 2] No such fine or directory: 'my_file.txt''

Comment: What error did you receive? It's working fine on my end

Comment: i need to make it as well where after it asks for the word or phrase that the user is looking for it then asks where to look and once that is entered it needs to parse though and find that word or phrase and then come back with that word or phrase and the number of times it showed up

Comment: That's probably beyond the scope of this question. Let's fix your current problem, then after you've drafted some code for your additional features, put up another question if you get stuck. Based on SO rules, if you start asking in this question for instructions on something you haven't drafted yet, your post will get flagged. Do you have an error for what's still going wrong?

Comment: ok i figured out that error the user would have to in this case have access to the code and understand how that works then need sot go into line 2 and change the file path to be the exact directory/file/folder and the name of the document in it. i need it where it asks for the input in the command prompt

Comment: So, the code is working now, so long as the file is my_file.txt as listed in the original post, correct? I added a line that allows you to specify the file name so long as it is in the same folder as your program. If you are wanting to be able to specify a path to somewhere else, etc. You'll need to start another question and try drafting up the code first.

Comment: I hope this is ok to ask but is their a easy way to be able to make it where if it can look though more then one file at a time for instance if i tell it to go into a file that has 3 documents then it will look for that word or phrase within all 3 of the documents.

Comment: It is definitely beyond the scope of this question because to ask you need to be able to show what you have already tried and your current post has no such attempts. So I'll give you a hint where to start. Mark this question complete ((assuming your program is currently running as originally asked)) then look up os.listdir() which is a function that can do what you are talking about. Try to use it, and if you get stuck, just ask an updated question about your new problem.